# When to use Intents(putextra,getextra) & When to use Arguments(set,get) to pass data in ANDROID

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

### I am trying to learn passing data in android

1. So far i was using [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to send data between the two
   different activities
2. Now, when i started learning fragments, i notice that when i deal
   with `interfragment communication` from developers site between 2 fragments in single
   activity i am passing data as `setArguments` and `getArguments`

---

***im-confused***

---

**My Questions**::

- When should we use `Intents` & When should we use `set-arguments` &
  `get-arguments`
- what is the difference between using them
- More information on this would be helpful

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Intents** are used for communication between different activities and **set-arguments** are used for communication between two fragments. You can check this link- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface

Answer (score 1):

Intent is always good to send the primitives/Strings/Object etc. between two different activities while when we wants to send data between two different fragment it is good to send/pass them as Bundle args.

Intents are message passing system used for communication between two different activities while on the other hand the same communication is better with setting and getting bundle arguments in case of fragments.